# complex adb command in python script not working

Tags: android, python, shell, scripting, adb

I want to run this command in a script

```
am broadcast -a com.test_event -e data '{ "eventType" : "atlastest", "name" : “backlight" }'
```

My script says

```
subprocess.Popen('adb shell "am broadcast -a com.test_event -e data \'{ \"eventType\" : \"atlastest\", \"name\" : \"backlight\" }\'"')
```

However when I run this it takes only a part of this statement upto the word event. This is the result.

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.preva.mpaqtapp.test_event (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

How do I change this so the entire command is run?

Comment: Are you saying this based on Broadcasting print

Comment: That and I don't see any change in the backlight on the device.

Comment: has extras means it includes all params you sent. Can you execute that in adb shell and show us the output?

Comment: found the solution. Apparently the quotes have to be escaped thrice. This works for me - cmd = "adb shell am broadcast -a com.test_event -e data \'{ \\\"eventType\\\" : \\\"atlastest\\\", \\\"name\\\" : \\\"backlight\\\" }\'"